# I am getting undefined value when i try to get parent id of span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `undefined` value when I try to get parent id of `span`.

This is my code:

```
<span id="test">sskdfj <span>test</span> asdkfwsfe</span>
```

```
$(obj).closest().attr('id');
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML too.

Comment: ...or go to psychics overflow...

Comment: I agree you need to post the HTML, it is possible that the return value of closest is undefined, or the value closest exists but there is no attribute 'id' which results to undefined.

Comment: I am using html code <span id="test">sskdfj <span>test</span> asdkfwsfe</span>

Comment: But you need to edit the question to include the HTML or we can't help you.

Comment: What is `obj` and what is your HTML?

Comment: For GOD sake! please post the questions correctly. We need HTML, and your script in order to help you out

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a selector to `closest()` to get any results from it.

If you want the parent element, use `parent()`, not `closest()`.

```
$(obj).parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: I used it but again geting same problem undefined value.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/H9Q7T/ - Most likely, the parent of `obj` doesn't have an id.

Comment: yes it work my whole code is                                    <span id="spn8">
<span onclick="changeText1(this,event)">[ This note is for an FMLA condition]</span>
</span>

function changeText1(obj,event)
{
       
  var pid=  $(obj).parent().attr('id')
  alert(pid);
  
}                                                                   Please help i am not getting erro

Comment: That code does give me errors. You're missing a semi-colon after `('id')`. If I [put one in](http://jsbin.com/uYIBeGE/1/), then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <span id="test_2"></span>
</div>
```

In your code `obj` is `#test_2`. You want to get `#test`. You should give a selector to the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to select an element, otherwise jQuery doesn't know what to select.

```
$("#test_2").closest("#test").attr('ID')
```

Or, as Quentin stated, use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead if that's the element you want to select.

```
$("#test_2").parent().attr('ID')
```

Check it out here: <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PAVQx/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, separate out your JS code and use a class.

```
<span id="spn8">
  <span class="clickable">[This note is for an FMLA condition]</span>
</span>

function changeText1(obj,event) { 
  var pid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  alert(pid);
}

$('.clickable').click(changeText1); // 'spn8'
```